# My friend and I cannot ping eachother, yet other internet services work fine

Tags: networking, routes, ip

A bit of a weird situation that I haven't come across. Note: it's not really a problem and I'm just really asking this out of interest.

My friend switched to a new ISP (same ISP as me, he lives one city over) and they just installed the new router today. He asked for my IP to join my teamspeak server which is temporarily being hosted on my local machine. He's joined it before many times without issue. He said it's not working today.

I told him to ping me, no response. I pinged him, also no response. At this point I was confused since I had never come across this situation before (maybe it's common, I'm no networking expert though). I ran a tracert and told him to do the same, mine reached a domain which was prefixed with his city name and his reached a domain prefixed with my city name, both timed out before actually reaching the destination IP.

At this point we decided to just use Discord instead and assumed this problem would resolve itself, I tried one last thing. I ssh'd into my work development server located in London and did a trace to both IPs. My IP traced fine and his IP timed out.

All I can think of is that routing tables for his new router aren't properly set up yet, my knowledge on networking doesn't really extend beyond this! I'm really just interested in what's going on here and would love an answer from a networking expert!

Comment: It is possible to disallow (effectively disable) ping at the ISP.

Answer (score 0):

ICMP protocol might be disabled or blocked at any hop along the way, which would disrupt tracert.

Given that you tried pinging from two different endpoints to his PC could indicate that the ICMP blocking is happening somewhere closer to his endpoint.

With regards to the teamspeak connection, his new router might not be configured to allow the appropriate ports through. All home routers have different ways of configuring port-forwarding, but I'd check documentation there.